# why infimum come infront of supremum?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I was reading a book  of  **Rudin**:- Real and  complex analysis, i got some doubt in the given below theorem

Theorem $1.14$ : If $ f_n : X \to [ -\infty , \infty] $ is measurable  for $n=1 ,2,3,...,$ and $$g= \sup_{n \ge 1} f_n$$ , $$h= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup f_n$$ then $g$ and $h$ are measurable

Proof : $g^{-1}( (\alpha, \infty ] ) = \cup _{n=1}^{\infty} f_n^{-1} ( \alpha, \infty]$ Hence Theorem $1.12(c)$ implies that $g$ is measurable. The same result holds of course with inf in place of sup, and
since $$h= \inf _{k\ge 1} \{ \sup_{i \ge k} f_i\}$$ its follow that $h$ is  measurable

My attempt : from the given theorem i understand that

$g^{-1}( (\alpha, \infty ] ) = \cup _{n=1}^{\infty} f_n^{-1} ( \alpha, \infty]$

$h^{-1}( [- \infty, \alpha) ) = \cup _{n=1}^{\infty} f_n^{-1} ( [-\infty,\alpha)$

**My doubt** :My confusion is about infimum . Im not getting  why

$$h= \inf _{k\ge 1} \{ \sup_{i \ge k} f_i\}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup f_n ?$$

Here  why infimum come infront of supremum ?

Comment: Isn't that the definition of $\limsup$?

Comment: @ArcticChar lim sup =sup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sequence can hit values higher than the lim sup, provided it does so only a finitely many number of times.

$\sup a_n \ge \limsup a_n$

But if we ignore a large enough block at the front of the sequence, the large values slip out of the sub-sequence we are evaluating.  The supremum of this right hand tail is getting smaller as we drop values from the left-hand side.  The smallest measure of the supremum of sub-sequences is the lim sup of the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Because, by definition, given a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$, its superior limit is$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n=\inf_{k\geqslant1}\left(\sup_{n\geqslant k}a_n\right).$$